# while importing map projects into workspace it always gives an error at res/values-v11 folder.

Tags: android, eclipse, dictionary, geolocation, android-maps-v2

error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light'.

Suppose if i delete that style xml file means. Error gone.
Why this error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

> Make sure your build target is set to API13

Comment: when i click the tick mark. it said that u accept answer in 5 minutes. But it will not accept when i clicked that many times.

Comment: click toggle again means.

Comment: i didnt get ur query?

Comment: @Stack28 i am doing one project for taxi booking application. in this application i created list view item. when any one of the list item is clicked then it will go through into the map activity. In this map activity will show the details of that particular car selected. Its detail was retrieve from the server.

Comment: sorry for my lower english friend.@Stacks28

Comment: for that above details how to retrieve data from server, when i am click the list item.